# Error trying to re-register even if jpa child key exists

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```java
// Service
@Transactional
    public Account joinByInputJoinAccount(InputJoinAccount inputJoinAccount) {

        Account.AccountBuilder accountBuilder = Account.builder()
                .userid(inputJoinAccount.getUserid())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(inputJoinAccount.getPassword()))
                .name(inputJoinAccount.getName())
                .phoneNumber(inputJoinAccount.getPhoneNumber());

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(inputJoinAccount.getBirthDate())) {
            accountBuilder.birthDate(LocalDate.parse(inputJoinAccount.getBirthDate()));
        }
        accountBuilder.activated(true);

        Account account = accountBuilder.build();
        account.addAuthorities(Set.of(AccountAuthority.builder().authority(Authority.builder().authorityName("ROLE_INSTITUTE").build()).build()));

        return accountRepository.save(account);
    }



// Acount
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account extends BaseEntity {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<AccountAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    ...

    public void addAuthorities(Set<AccountAuthority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
        authorities.forEach(accountAuthority -> accountAuthority.setAccount(this));
    }
}

// AccountAuthority
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_authority")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AccountAuthority extends BaseEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AccountAuthorityId id = new AccountAuthorityId();

    @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    @MapsId("accountId")
    private Account account;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "authority_name")
    @MapsId("authorityName")
    private Authority authority;

    @Builder
    public AccountAuthority(Account account, Authority authority) {
        this.account = account;
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    @Embeddable
    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public static class AccountAuthorityId implements Serializable {
        private Long accountId;
        private String authorityName;
    }
}

// Authority 
@Entity
@Table(name = "authority")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Authority extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "authority_name", length = 50)
    private String authorityName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "authority")
    private Set<AccountAuthority> accountAuthorities;

    @Builder
    public Authority(String authorityName) {
        this.authorityName = authorityName;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJFqv.png)

Error trying to re-register even if jpa child key exists

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "authority_pkey"
Detail: Key (authority_name)=(ROLE_INSTITUTE) already exists.

I have a problem trying to register even though I have a jpa permission key. I don't know why. Help me

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a new `Authority` with the same `authorityName` as one already present in the db. Instead of building a new object you can retrieve a jpa reference or an entity from db. So instead of

```
Authority authority = Authority.builder().authorityName("ROLE_INSTITUTE").build()
account.addAuthorities(Set.of(authority));
```

you should do one of the following

```
Authority authority = entityManager.getReference(Authority.class, "ROLE_INSTITUTE");
account.addAuthorities(Set.of(authority));
```

or

```
Authority authority = authorityRepository.findById("ROLE_INSTITUTE");
account.addAuthorities(Set.of(authority));
```